# Create custom log ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, logs, authentication

I use ubuntu and would like to create a custom log for the authentication information on the server.

It is currently written in `/var/log/auth.log`

Would it be possible besides write it in `auth.log` it also save the information in a `new.log`?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 which uses `rsyslog` as its syslog daemon. You can do the following as root:

```
echo 'auth,authpriv.* /var/log/new.log' >> /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
systemctl restart rsyslog
```